# Fabric not working when using ~/.ssh/config

Tags: python, bash, ssh, fabric

I have the following configuration on my ~/.ssh/config

```
Host death-star
    HostName deathstar.empire.com
    User vader
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/death_id_rsa
```

And the following fabfile

```
from fabric.api import env, task

env.use_ssh_config = True

@task
def destroy_rebels():
    run("echo Alderaan has been destroyed")
```

I'm calling the task like this:

```
$ fab --host death-star destroy_rebels
```

This is the output I get:

```
[death-star] Executing task 'destroy_rebels'
[death-star] run: echo Alderaan has been destroyed

Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code -1 while executing!

Requested: echo Alderaan has been destroyed
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "echo Alderaan has been destroyed"

Aborting.
Disconnecting from vader@deathstar.empire.com... done.
```

I'm pretty sure the ssh config is correct since I can `ssh death-star` with no problems.

Also, when I specify the hostname and use the default key for user root instead of using the ssh config file, it works:

```
$ fab --user root --host deathstar.empire.com destroy_rebels
```

Any ideas why this happens?

**EDIT**: This is my fabric version

```
$ fab --version
Fabric 1.4.1
ssh (library) 1.7.13
```

**EDIT 2**:

I've rewritten bits of the original post. I realized that the `root` (using the default key `id_rsa` always works, even using  `.ssh/config`, if I add a new entry:

```
Host root-death-star
    HostName deathstar.empire.com
    User root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa


$ fab --host root-death-star destroy_rebels # this works
```

But using the non-root user `vader`, with its own key `death_id_rsa`, it doesnt. SSHing to the server is still working though, as root and as vader.

Comment: Well, you have a typo in IdentityFile, is that just a copy/paste issue?

Comment: Can you include the output of `fab --version`? (`use_ssh_config` was added in 1.4). Oh, and in your last example, does `--user vader` work? (you may also need `-i ~/ssh/id_rsa`)

Comment: One more thing to try is expanding the `~` in your `.ssh/config` to `/home/whatever` - it could be that ssh expands tildes, but the python ssh library isn't.

Comment: Usually the IdentityFile is `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (note the period). Is that a typo as well? You say you can `ssh death-star` with no problems, but it would also respond if you have defined death-star in your /etc/hosts. If it is, does it still work if you remove it from there?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo (bad idea to make the post star wars themed).  I have not defined `death-star` in my /etc/hosts file.

Comment: if you ssh in as vader and run: /bin/bash -l -c "echo Alderaan has been destroyed" what do you get? maybe your profile scripts are broken

Comment: @benmmurphy: Wow, that is interesting, this is what I get:

`zsh: segmentation fault  /bin/bash -l -c "echo Alderaan has been destroyed"`

Maybe it is an issue with `zsh` (which is the default shell for user `vader` on the remote server)?

Comment: It was an issue with `bash` on the remote machine for that particular user. I created a new user and used that instead and everything works now. I still don't know what is the issue with my first user though. I realized that I have the same issue with a couple more users, all of which use zsh as the default shell.

Answer (score 0):

From that output it's nothing to do with the ssh connection but what the return code from the echo being run is returning. As to what would make it the -1, from your additional notes, it could be that something custom in your zsh or zshrc is throwing a bad return code and it's bubbling up.